# UI gets disturbed whiloe scrolling down using StaggeredGridView android

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

I am using https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView Library to show a staggered grid within my app. Everytinh works fine. But If I scroll to the very bottom of the page the UI gets disturbed like below.[image]

I have no idea on why this is happening. Can anyone point out the issue?

Comment: Did you get any solution for the same ?